# google maps search by label does not work anymore

Tags: search, google-search, google-maps

Since around February 2024 I can not search locations by self-added labels anymore.

E.g. my parking spot has the label "p9 parking". In the past, it was enough to type p9 to be able to select this location either on my mobile as on my notebook. Now it does not even appear if I type the complete label in the search.

**Plattform:**

I have this issue as well on

- Chrome on my Ubuntu 22.04 Notebook and on
- the google maps app on my Android phone

**Issues of other users:**

In February 2022 a user posted the same issue in the Google support forum:

https://support.google.com/maps/thread/149985771/can-t-search-by-saved-places-labels-anymore?hl=en

Though no one posted a solution over there.

**Suspected fault localization:**

I tested the functionality with a different account and there it works as I want.

Based on where and when the issue is happening I assume it is not a matter of the device or software version but with the user settings.

edit:
**testing**
After I saw that some rarely used labels are still proposed in the location search I did a lot of testing.
I deleted + created + renamed a lot of labels.

**solution hint**
To create the same label on the neighbor building works. Deleting the label and creating a new one on the correct building works not.

To be precise: the three most used locations can not be found via my label. All others I tested do work. It seems like Google trys to force me to use the "home" and "work" label. (Which I do not want to use since they are not accurate.)

**Question**
Does anyone have a solution for this problem?